# Getting a list of _ids from MongoDB - Avoiding 'distinct too big'

Tags: python, mongodb, list, pymongo, distinct

I have a file which scrapes the data from a sitemap .xml file, and downloads some data from each page. Each time I start the scrape function, I go to this xml to get the URLs to scrape, put them in a list, compare them to the list of url's which I've already downloaded, and therefore just scrape the remainder. I use these URLs as the _id of a mongodb:

```
list_of_ids = collection.find().distinct('_id')
start_urls = list(set(new_url_list)-(set(list_of_ids)))
```

I've now come under a point of receiving the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: distinct too big, 16mb cap, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'distinct too big, 16mb cap', 'code': 17217, 'codeName': 'Location17217'}
```

I assume I could just iterate through the database and append each _id to a list, but whilst I'm not hell-bent on performance, there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_id`s have to be distinct, so not sure why you need to use distinct at all, unless it's an easy way to get a list without the clutter.

Try this instead:

```
list_of_ids = [x['_id'] for x in collection.find({}, {'_id': 1})]
```

In fact if you want a set, use the similar:

```
set_of_ids = {x['_id'] for x in collection.find({}, {'_id': 1})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the distinct function of `pymongo` which directly returns you a list

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db = mongo[dbname][collectionname]

distinct_list = db.distinct('_id')
```